# Show less/more text with angularjs if text is formatted as html

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I have read stackoverflow questions about hiding and showing long text using angularjs.
My problem is that my text from server side is returned as html text, with hrefs, and 
 tags, or I could return it as Markdown and then parse on angular client side.

Problem is that how to cut text to short display version, if that text has html or markdown tags in it ?

In one of answers i found a directive to cut long text and show More / Less links

https://github.com/kipernicus/angularjs-directive/blob/master/js/directives/expand-text.js

```
angular.module("answer", []).directive("expandText", function() {
    function truncateWordBounds(full, len) {
        var last = full.substr(len, 1);
        var abbrev = full.substr(0, len);
        if (RegExp(/[A-Za-z]/).test(last)) {
        abbrev = abbrev.replace(/[A-Za-z]+$/, '');
        }
        return {truncated : abbrev, expanded: full.substr(abbrev.length)};
    }
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        templateUrl: "partials/expand-text.html",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            showMoreLabel: "@showMoreLabel",
            showLessLabel: "@showLessLabel"
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            var maxLength = attributes["maxLength"] || 100;
            scope.text = attributes["text"];
            if(scope.text.length < maxLength) {
                scope.disabled = true; // no need for truncation
            }
            else {
                scope.truncated = true;
                var splitText = truncateWordBounds(scope.text, maxLength);
                scope.text = splitText.truncated;
                scope.expandedText = splitText.expanded;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

But if that directive receives html text it throws error

```
Error: String contains an invalid character
```

and also this directive can cut html tag in two parts, and that text would be broken.

**So my question would be in two parts:**

1. How to better store user input in server side, that would show href links and "\n" after outputing and it would be possible to toggle short / long text version
2. How angularjs code would look like, so it would parse html or markdown to toggle short / long text version

**EDIT:**

I partly solved problem with expand/collapse by using angular and css solutions, this also solves problem parsing html text.

```
.expand-wrapper {
    &.text-expanded {
        .text-container {
            overflow: visible;
            height: auto;
        }
        .btn-text-expand {
            .hidden;
        }
    }
    &.text-hidden {
        .text-container {
            height: 40px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .btn-text-collapse {
            .hidden;
        }
    }
}


<div class="expand-wrapper" ng-class="{ 'text-expanded': show, 'text-hidden': !show }">
    <div class="text-container">
        Long text goes here....            
    </div>
    <button class="btn-text-expand" ng-click="show = true">Show text</button>
    <button class="btn-text-collapse" ng-click="show = false">Hide text</button>
</div>
```

**But how I could hide "Show button" if text size is less than 40px in height ?** because there will be nothing to expand

Comment: `RegExp(/[A-Za-z]/).test(last)` will never work: Use `/[A-Za-z]/.test(last)` or `(new RegExp('[A-Za-z]')).test(last)`. Add the global flag as well `/.../g` or `new RegExp('...', 'g')`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `textContainer.getBoundingClientRect().height` to get the text height and either bind the condition to the button's `ng-show` attribute or apply it directly in your code that handles the server response.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answer provided above, here is what I did to hide the "show" button. I created a directive on the  element to set a scope property based on that element's height and used it on the "show" button:

```
       link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.getElementDimensions = function () {
                return { 'ht': element.height() };
            };

            scope.$watch(
                scope.getElementDimensions,
                function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    if (newValue.ht > 40) {
                        scope.showMoreButton = true;
                    }
                },
                true
            );

            element.bind('load', function () {
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
```

You can use this showMoreButton prop on the "show" button:

```
<button class="btn-text-expand" ng-click="show = true" ng-show="showMoreButton">Show text</button>
```